# how to refactor functions that have same lines with only difference being one function call?

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Consider following code snippet

```
template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(size_t count)
{
    size_t prev_count = Count();
    if(count < prev_count)
    {
       DestroyMemory(prev_count, count);
    }
    else if(count > prev_count)
    {
      Reserve(count);

      for(size_t i=prev_count; i<count; i++)
      {
         // change in function call
         m_block.DefaultConstruct();
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is an overload for the same function

```
  template<typename T>
  void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(const T &object, size_t count)
  {
     size_t prev_count = Count();
    if(count < prev_count)
    {
       DestroyMemory(prev_count, count);
    }
    else if(count > prev_count)
    {
      Reserve(count);

      for(size_t i=prev_count; i<count; i++)
      {
         // change in function call
         m_block.CopyConstruct(object);
      }
    }
  }
```

One way, I think of refactoring resize function is to provide const T *pObject as a default argument. And check if is provided, then, call CopyConstruct.

Another way could be provide make one resize a kind of a wrapper which calls the other resize.

What is the best approach?

Comment: What is `m_block` and why do you have those `DefaultConstruct()` and `CopyConstruct()` calls instead of using e.g. the assignment operator (which would then make both functions be identical and allow you to just specify a default parameter value)?

Comment: m_block is an object hold contiguous block of memory.

Comment: If the given size is greater than the current count, additional elements will be default constructed up to the new count. If the given size is less than the current size, elements after this size will be destroyed.

Comment: I would have both variants of reserve call a common function that is being passed a closure (if you're using C++11).
In other words, construct a closure which is either `DefaultConstruct` or `CopyConstruct` and pass it to a common implementation. Did not post this as an answer, as am not sure if you're on C++11/14.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am developing a library that is not using c++11/14.

Comment: Well, why don't you just drop the `DefaultConstruct()` version entirely, add a default parameter like `const T &object = T()`, and use `CopyConstruct(object)`? This is how many implementations of `std::vector` ultimately operate as well (a lot of `std::vector` resize implementations end up boiling down to `erase` and `insert` calls rather than performing the work on their own). Is there some particular reason you want to avoid e.g. `CopyConstruct(T())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to create a dummy object that you could pass into a new function `m_block.Construct()` to indicate that it's default-construction:

```
struct default_construct_t { };
```

Which we use on our end like:

```
template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    resize(count, default_construct_t());
}

template <typename T, typename Obj>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(size_t count, Obj const& obj)
{
    size_t prev_count = Count();
    if(count < prev_count)
    {
       DestroyMemory(prev_count, count);
    }
    else if(count > prev_count)
    {
      Reserve(count);

      for(size_t i=prev_count; i<count; i++)
      {
         // change in function call
         m_block.Construct(obj);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you just have to provide overloads for `Construct(default_construct_t )` and `Construct(T const& )`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "the best approach" that will apply universally, in every possible situation. For example, if code bloat is not a concern, you can have a pair of facades to a common function, that pass an appropriate lambda to the common function:

```
template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(size_t count)
{
    resize_common(count, [] { m_block.DefaultConstruct(); });
}

template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(const T &object, size_t count)
{
    resize_common(count, [&] { m_block.CopyConstruct(object); });
}

template <typename T, typename lambda_t>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize_common(size_t count, lambda_t &&lambda)
{
    size_t prev_count = Count();
    if(count < prev_count)
    {
       DestroyMemory(prev_count, count);
    }
    else if(count > prev_count)
    {
      Reserve(count);

      for(size_t i=prev_count; i<count; i++)
      {
         lambda();
      }
    }
}
```

If code bloat is a concern, then a variation of what you, yourself, offered as a possibility:

```
template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(size_t count)
{
    resize_common(count, null);
}

template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize(const T &object, size_t count)
{
    resize_common(count, &object);
}

template <typename T>
void MyDynamicArray<T>::resize_common(size_t count, const T *object)
{
    size_t prev_count = Count();
    if(count < prev_count)
    {
       DestroyMemory(prev_count, count);
    }
    else if(count > prev_count)
    {
      Reserve(count);

      for(size_t i=prev_count; i<count; i++)
      {
         if (object)
              m_block.CopyConstruct(*object);
         else
              m_block.DefaultConstruct();
      }
    }
}
```

I'm sure that one can think of a few variations of the same. The bottom line is that to answer "which one is the best", one has to take into consideration the individual requirements you have, consider how well each alternative implementation meets the requirements, and pick one of them. Should code bloat be minimized? Is overall performance an issue? etc...